# Eroor: $ ssh: Could not resolve hostname [HOSTNAME]: Name or service not known

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, bastion

I am on windows 10 machine. I need to ssh to our Bastion and then do port forwarding to connect to AWS instance. I have a config file that I use to ssh.
My config file is as following:

```
Host [host]
  IdentityFile myprivatekey
  CheckHostIP no
  HostName [myhostname]
  User myuser
  LocalForward 3900 ip-XX.XXX.XX.XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal:3389
```

When I do `ssh [host]`
I get the following error:

> Error: $ ssh: Could not resolve hostname [HOSTNAME]: Name or service not known

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. I recreated my private key and i moved to .ssh folder then i changed the path in my config file to :

~/.ssh/myprivatekey

Then it worked..

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a dns issue.

To figure out, try in cmd.exe : ping myhostname

It should not work.

Then you have two option :

- add myhostname in your dns server

Or

- add myhostname 1.2.3.4 (replace 1.2.3.4 with correct ip) in system32\driver\etc\hosts